# more than 350000 page within same sharepoint 2013 library

Tags: publishing-site, large-lists

I want to use SharePoint to build news site, this site will publish more than 200 page every day, and there are around 350000 archive news required to migrate to this site. And there are a lot of custom web part will build to show these news.

My questions, can I save all these pages in one SharePoint 2013 Pages library? Is there any performance issues with this amount?

Comment: Ideally it depends on your architecture and solution design. You should check the boundaries of a library on how much items it can store but these limits are recommendations and not hard limits.

You could use separate out your pages on to different library, perhaps use a different one for each quarter or for 6 months. You could use search webparts to display the content on to users which should perform better than other methods, again it depends on your hardware configuration and topology.

Comment: @Manu the requirements is create a library can constants more than 350000 page, using OOTB features. I'll use default SharePoint views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store as many as `30,000,000` pages in a library. Remember that each page represents a list item in the library. However, there is something called `List view threshold`.

> It specifies the maximum number of list or library items that a
>   database operation, such as a query, can process at the same time
>   outside the daily time window set by the administrator during which
>   queries are unrestricted.It only affects the view of the item and does
>   not affect the maximum number of list items in a list.

So as long as you are not breaching the `List view threshold` limits, there should not be any performance issues.
Also see this for boundary limits in SharePoint: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#ListLibrary

Answer (score 0):

Our organization has a library that has close to 1,000,000 documents in a single library which is far from the limit.

One of the biggest hurdles is the list view threshold which throttles the number of items that can be returned in a single view.  By default, this is set to 5,000 and it's not recommended that you change this.

Keep the list view threshold in mind when you're designing views for the library and aim for the criteria of the view to return results totaling less then the threshold and ensure that the first sort by is based on an indexed column.  Views could be along the lines of 'Created/Modified this week' for example (if suitable).

We found that Explorer view will not cope well with this volume of documents and
   most likely won't open at all which can be an issue if it's used to add documents to, or manage the library.  There isn't a figure at which explorer view 'breaks' but it seems to be a combination between volume of documents and size.  You can work around this by sub-dividing your document library using folders so that explorer view is not retrieving as much documents in one operation.

Lastly, consider implementing an information management policy that could move old/archived pages to a separate library to keep volumes in the main one down.